# Rating Value Display Wrong In collection View

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on third party cosmos view in my E-commerce Application.I am already completed Display Rating value on Cosmos View But I have issue when I will scroll Collectionview , Scroll time Display rating Value will changed.I cant understand why Rating Value Changed when I scroll collectionview.

Anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

- check carefully your passing correct values in cellForItemAtIndexPath for each and every cell. issue seems like if/else tableview reusable cells.
- check each and every if else conditions and assign right values all times.

you can share your "cellForItemAtIndexPath" code so we can help you.

Comment: I added cellForItemAtIndexPath method Above

Answer (score 0):

My cellForRow Method

let cellHomeProductCell: CltnHomeProductCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CltHomeProductCell", for: indexPath) as! CltnHomeProductCell

```
 cellHomeProductCell.setUpBestSellerData(arrModelDataBestSeller: arrBestSellerData)

        let dict = arrBestSellerData[indexPath.row] as! [String:AnyObject]

        // Rating Value Set
        let rate = PIService.getStringFromDict(dict: dict, key: "avg_rating")
        print(rate)

        let value = Double(rate)
        print(value)

        if value != nil
        {
            cellHomeProductCell.ratingView.rating = value!
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

cellHomeProductCell.setUpBestSellerData(arrModelDataBestSeller: arrBestSellerData)

```
    let dict = arrBestSellerData[indexPath.row] as! [String:AnyObject]

    // Rating Value Set
    let rate = PIService.getStringFromDict(dict: dict, key: "avg_rating")
    print(rate)

    let value = Double(rate)
    print(value)

    if value != nil
    {
        cellHomeProductCell.ratingView.rating = value!
    }else{
        print("Found nil value")
        cellHomeProductCell.ratingView.rating = 0.0
    }
```

Comment: Now My CellForRow issue is solved. Thank you Rahul_Chandnani

Comment: Your welcome.
Always remember you should assign values for if and else both conditions.